# How to get the enable / disable a scheduled task using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, scheduled-tasks, windows-xp-sp3

Using C# (.net Framework 4.0) and Windows XP is it possible to enable/disable a Schedulled Task programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/):

> This project provides a single assembly wrapper for the 1.0 and 2.0 versions of Task Scheduler found in all Microsoft operating systems post Windows 98. It simplifies the coding, aggregates the multiple versions, provides an editor and allows for localization support.

Comment: As the project description state it's just a wrapper around the COM component. You can access the scheduler directly through COM if you don't want to use this 3rd party library.

Comment: @DanBusha indeed, but it makes it easier this way and I got what I needed. Thanks :)

Comment: I do not see this working in .Net framework 4.5.2. I am unable to get list of all the tasks.